# change how eclipse auto generated code looks

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to change how auto generated code looks in eclipse?

Currently it generate code like

```
   int a = something;
```

But I would really like it do do it like

```
   int a=something
```

That is: Without all that extra space. This also goes for functions, where there is an extra space before the ,

I would really prefer f(int a,int b); instead of f(int a, int b);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always change the way your code is formatted in your preferences under Java --> Code-Style --> Formatter. Modify the existing styles or just create your own.
There's also a tab for white spaces. Just uncheck those `before/after comma` options.
Code already written can be formatted automatically by pressing `ctrl + shift + f`.
(or `cmd + shift + f` on a Mac).
[image]
Example for methods:
[image]
Assignments without spaces:
[image]